# Read arrays from file

Tags: python, arrays, file

I need to read points from 2 files (.txt or .xls) as an array, and combine them to run an algorithm that fits these points into an ellipse.

From the first file of 5 columns I have to read the arrays X's of 5 elements:

```
3586,02124  2391,50342  837,45227   -837,29681  -2385,9751
3587,69238  2387,48218  836,604     -840,75067  -2390,17529
3588,44531  2387,44556  836,00555   -840,79022  -2389,77612
3588,08203  2388,25439  836,26544   -840,17017  -2389,07544
3587,66553  2389,05566  836,53046   -839,53912  -2388,40405
3587,26636  2389,86255  836,79382   -838,91455  -2387,7168
........
```

From the second file of 5 columns I have to read the arrays Y's of 5 elements:

```
843,19598   2396,10278  3579,1377   4210,15674  4209,37549
841,9397    2397,21948  3573,11963  4205,89209  4226,73926
842,01642   2397,72266  3573,06494  4202,88379  4226,93799
842,22083   2397,47974  3574,27515  4204,19043  4223,8208
842,42065   2397,20142  3575,47437  4205,52246  4220,64795
......
```

Then I must create the variable pot:

```
pot = (x, y)
```

Which is the input data for calculation. The first line of the first file `(x(1))` corresponds to the first line of the second file `(y(1))`. The algorithm takes x and y from these five points 
`(3586,02124;843,19598), (2391,50342; 2396,10278),....` and fits the ellipse. So for each sets of point (or line) I will have an ellipse.

To sum it up, I am looking for a code to read these points and also which loop will be suitable to run the algorithm for each set of points.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your own effort and code as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Files to read
files = ['f1.csv', 'f2.csv']

# Read each file and create a dataframe
# df[0] contains a dataframe for f1
# df[1] contains a dataframe for f2
df = []
for file in files:
    df.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep='\\s+', header=None))

print(f'Dataframe of f1\n{df[0]}\n')
print(f'Dataframe of f2\n{df[1]}\n')

# Get the number of rows from df[0]
# df[1] must be of the same dimension (rows x columns)
nrows = df[0].shape[0]
ncols = df[0].shape[1]

for row in range(nrows):
    print(f'\nrow {row}')
    for col in range(ncols):
        print(f'col {col} of f1 and f2')
        col_f1 = df[0].iloc[row, col].split(',')
        col_f2 = df[1].iloc[row, col].split(',')
        print(f'{col_f1}, {col_f2}')
        # Here you have (3586,02124;843,19598)....
        # In this format: col_f1, col_f2 = [3586, 02124], [843, 19598]...
        # Don't forget to convert to float() the numbers
        # Ex. pt_x = float(col_f1[0])
```

#### Which Yields:

```
Dataframe of f1
            0           1          2           3            4
0  3586,02124  2391,50342  837,45227  -837,29681   -2385,9751
1  3587,69238  2387,48218    836,604  -840,75067  -2390,17529
2  3588,44531  2387,44556  836,00555  -840,79022  -2389,77612
3  3588,08203  2388,25439  836,26544  -840,17017  -2389,07544
4  3587,66553  2389,05566  836,53046  -839,53912  -2388,40405

Dataframe of f2
           0           1           2           3           4
0  843,19598  2396,10278   3579,1377  4210,15674  4209,37549
1   841,9397  2397,21948  3573,11963  4205,89209  4226,73926
2  842,01642  2397,72266  3573,06494  4202,88379  4226,93799
3  842,22083  2397,47974  3574,27515  4204,19043   4223,8208
4  842,42065  2397,20142  3575,47437  4205,52246  4220,64795


row 0
col 0 of f1 and f2
['3586', '02124'], ['843', '19598']
col 1 of f1 and f2
['2391', '50342'], ['2396', '10278']
col 2 of f1 and f2
['837', '45227'], ['3579', '1377']
col 3 of f1 and f2
['-837', '29681'], ['4210', '15674']
col 4 of f1 and f2
['-2385', '9751'], ['4209', '37549']

row 1
col 0 of f1 and f2
['3587', '69238'], ['841', '9397']
col 1 of f1 and f2
['2387', '48218'], ['2397', '21948']
col 2 of f1 and f2
['836', '604'], ['3573', '11963']
col 3 of f1 and f2
['-840', '75067'], ['4205', '89209']
col 4 of f1 and f2
['-2390', '17529'], ['4226', '73926']

row 2
col 0 of f1 and f2
['3588', '44531'], ['842', '01642']
col 1 of f1 and f2
['2387', '44556'], ['2397', '72266']
col 2 of f1 and f2
['836', '00555'], ['3573', '06494']
col 3 of f1 and f2
['-840', '79022'], ['4202', '88379']
col 4 of f1 and f2
['-2389', '77612'], ['4226', '93799']

row 3
col 0 of f1 and f2
['3588', '08203'], ['842', '22083']
col 1 of f1 and f2
['2388', '25439'], ['2397', '47974']
col 2 of f1 and f2
['836', '26544'], ['3574', '27515']
col 3 of f1 and f2
['-840', '17017'], ['4204', '19043']
col 4 of f1 and f2
['-2389', '07544'], ['4223', '8208']

row 4
col 0 of f1 and f2
['3587', '66553'], ['842', '42065']
col 1 of f1 and f2
['2389', '05566'], ['2397', '20142']
col 2 of f1 and f2
['836', '53046'], ['3575', '47437']
col 3 of f1 and f2
['-839', '53912'], ['4205', '52246']
col 4 of f1 and f2
['-2388', '40405'], ['4220', '64795']
```

You can continue from there, now (x,y) pairs are easily accessible. I don't know what do you want to do with pot = (x,y) so I can't help further.

Comment: Hi! many thanks! What I need is to read the first rows of each file, i.e.  x1 = (ColumnA1, ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5) and y1 = (ColumnB1, ColumnB2, ColumnB3, ColumnB4, ColumnB5) which are the x,y coordinates of the 5 points to be fitted.: 1st point = ( ColumnA1, ColumnB1) , 2nd point =  (ColumnA2, ColumnB2), and so on. Then, the variable  pot1 = (x1,y1) is the input for the algorithm that yields the parameters of the ellipse1. After this, the code has to continue with the second rows of the files, get the second set of points and give the second ellipse ellipse2

Comment: and then, continue with the third rows, and get the third ellipse ....

Comment: I will be able to take a look tomorrow. Meanwhile try to work on this code. I didn't optimize it to leave it as clear as possible.

Comment: My code to read the files x1 and y1 is:

import numpy as np

filenamex = 'xpr.txt'
filenamey = 'ypr.txt'
a = np.loadtxt(filenamex, delimiter=' ')
b = np.loadtxt(filenamey, delimiter=' ')

x= tuple(a)
y= tuple(b)

Comment: Thanks so much! It doesn´t solve my problem but I was no clear at all so I will make a new question.

Comment: Ok. Copy this code and detail more. Also, put some valid data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789843/read-lines-of-txt-or-excel-file-into-tuples

Comment: That's the new post I made.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly know what you mean but:

```
array = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip('\n').split('  '))
```

gives me this output:

```
['3586,02124', '2391,50342', '837,45227', ' -837,29681', '-2385,9751']
['3587,69238', '2387,48218', '836,604', '', ' -840,75067', '-2390,17529']
['3588,44531', '2387,44556', '836,00555', ' -840,79022', '-2389,77612']
['3588,08203', '2388,25439', '836,26544', ' -840,17017', '-2389,07544']
['3587,66553', '2389,05566', '836,53046', ' -839,53912', '-2388,40405']
['3587,26636', '2389,86255', '836,79382', ' -838,91455', '-2387,7168']
```

I think you'll be able to make it further. You might want to do another strip but that's your file that has an inconsistent spacing before the 4th column