# Read lines of .txt or excel file into tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I would like to read line by line two .txt files. THE FILES HAVE DATA DIVIDED IN FIVE COLUMNS

FILE_1:

```
843.19598 2396.10278 3579.13778 4210.15674 4209.37549
841.93976 2397.21948 3573.11963 4205.89209 4226.73926
842.01642 2397.72266 3573.06494 4202.88379 4226.93799
842.22083 2397.47974 3574.27515 4204.19043 4223.82088
842.42065 2397.20142 3575.47437 4205.52246 4220.64795
```

FILE_2:

```
3586.02124 2391.50342 837.45227 -837.29681 -2385.97513
3587.69238 2387.48218 836.60445 -840.75067 -2390.17529
3588.44531 2387.44556 836.00555 -840.79022 -2389.77612
3588.08203 2388.25439 836.26544 -840.17017 -2389.07544
3587.66553 2389.05566 836.53046 -839.53912 -2388.40405
```

Each line of the files must be converted into a tuple. For example for the first line of both files, the output should be:

```
FILE_1/1stLine = (843.19598, 2396.10278, 3579.13778, 4210.15674, 4209.37549)  

FILE_2/1stline = (3586.02124, 2391.50342, 837.45227, -837.29681, -2385.97513)
```

Then I need to combine the lines of these two files into a new variable called aux, in which the first element it's a line of FILE_1 and the second element it's the line of the same position in FILE_2

```
aux = (FILE_1/1stLine, FILE_2/1stline) ----- aux 1stLine
aux = (FILE_1/2ndLine, FILE_2/2ndline) ----- aux 2ndLine
.
.
aux = (FILE_1/LastLine, FILE_2/Lastline) ----- aux 2ndLastLine
```

For instance, taking the first lines of both files, the first aux must be:

```
((843.19598, 2396.10278, 3579.13778, 4210.15674, 4209.37549), (3586.02124, 2391.50342, 837.45227, -837.29681, -2385.97513))
```

Any ideas?

```py
f1 = open("FILE_1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("FILE_2.txt", "r")
for a in f1:
    for b in f2:
        x = tuple(a)
        y = tuple(b)
        aux = (x, y)
```

The results with this code is:

```
('8', '4', '3', '.', '1', '9', '5', '9', '8', ' ', '2', '3', '9', '6', '.', '1', '0', '2', '7', '8', ' ', '3', '5', '7', '9', '.', '1', '3', '7', '7', '8', ' ', '4', '2', '1', '0', '.', '1', '5', '6', '7', '4', ' ', '4', '2', '0', '9', '.', '3', '7', '5', '4', '9', '\n')
('3', '5', '8', '6', '.', '0', '2', '1', '2', '4', ' ', '2', '3', '9', '1', '.', '5', '0', '3', '4', '2', ' ', '8', '3', '7', '.', '4', '5', '2', '2', '7', ' ', '-', '8', '3', '7', '.', '2', '9', '6', '8', '1', ' ', '-', '2', '3', '8', '5', '.', '9', '7', '5', '1', '3', '\n')
(('8', '4', '3', '.', '1', '9', '5', '9', '8', ' ', '2', '3', '9', '6', '.', '1', '0', '2', '7', '8', ' ', '3', '5', '7', '9', '.', '1', '3', '7', '7', '8', ' ', '4', '2', '1', '0', '.', '1', '5', '6', '7', '4', ' ', '4', '2', '0', '9', '.', '3', '7', '5', '4', '9', '\n'), ('3', '5', '8', '6', '.', '0', '2', '1', '2', '4', ' ', '2', '3', '9', '1', '.', '5', '0', '3', '4', '2', ' ', '8', '3', '7', '.', '4', '5', '2', '2', '7', ' ', '-', '8', '3', '7', '.', '2', '9', '6', '8', '1', ' ', '-', '2', '3', '8', '5', '.', '9', '7', '5', '1', '3', '\n'))
```

Many thanks!

Instead of getting each element of f1/f2 like '843.19598', I need the elements without quotes like 843.19598.

Let me show the code to which these data is the input (there is a set of points as an example)

The problem is that I have to read x and y from these files, and for each set I need to fit an ellipse.

```py
import ellipses as el
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse



x = (5727.53135,  7147.62235, 10330.93573,  8711.17228, 7630.40262,
        4777.24983,  4828.27655,  9449.94416,  5203.81323,  6299.44811,
        6494.21906)

y = (67157.77567 , 66568.50068 , 55922.56257 , 54887.47348 ,
       65150.14064 , 66529.91705 , 65934.25548 , 55351.57612 ,
       63123.5103  , 67181.141725, 56321.36025)

data = (x, y)

lsqe = el.LSqEllipse()
lsqe.fit(data)
center, width, height, phi = lsqe.parameters()

print (center, width, height, phi)

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('equal')
ax.plot(data[0], data[1], 'ro', label='test data', zorder=1)

ellipse = Ellipse(xy=center, width=2*width, height=2*height, angle=np.rad2deg(phi),
               edgecolor='b', fc='None', lw=2, label='Fit', zorder = 2)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add this comment to the question. You can edit it. I added some tags to you question.

Comment: Done it, I added the code to fit data to ellipses.

Comment: You just have to do float(x) before plotting. It will convert string into float.

Comment: sorry, what you mean with float (x) before plotting?

Comment: To remove the quotes and use the values as numbers. This will solve the "Instead of getting each element of f1/f2 like '843.19598', I need the elements without quotes like 843.19598"

Answer (score 0):

#### The dataset

```
FILE 1 (saved as f1.csv and f1.xls)
843.19598 2396.10278 3579.13778 4210.15674 4209.37549
841.93976 2397.21948 3573.11963 4205.89209 4226.73926
842.01642 2397.72266 3573.06494 4202.88379 4226.93799
842.22083 2397.47974 3574.27515 4204.19043 4223.82088
842.42065 2397.20142 3575.47437 4205.52246 4220.64795

FILE 2 (saved as f2.csv and f2.xls)
3586.02124 2391.50342 837.45227 -837.29681 -2385.97513
3587.69238 2387.48218 836.60445 -840.75067 -2390.17529
3588.44531 2387.44556 836.00555 -840.79022 -2389.77612
3588.08203 2388.25439 836.26544 -840.17017 -2389.07544
3587.66553 2389.05566 836.53046 -839.53912 -2388.40405
```

#### Using import csv (works for ascii files, i.e. .csv, .txt etc.)

```
import csv

# Files to read
files = ['f1.csv', 'f2.csv']
tup_files = ()
aux = ()

# Read each file and concatenate to tup_files
for file in files:
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
        tmp_rows = ()
        for row in csv_reader:
            tmp_rows += (tuple(row), )  

    tup_files += (tmp_rows, )

for row_f1, row_f2 in zip(tup_files[0], tup_files[1]):
    aux += (row_f1, row_f2)

print(f'printing f1\n{tup_files[0]}\n')
print(f'printing f2\n{tup_files[1]}\n')
print(f'printing aux\n{aux}')
```

#### Using pandas (works for .xls)

```
import pandas as pd

# Files to read
files = ['f1.xls', 'f2.xls']
tup_files = ()
aux = ()

# Read each file and concatenate to tup_files
for file in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
    tup_files += (tuple(data.itertuples(index=False, name=None)), )

for row_f1, row_f2 in zip(tup_files[0], tup_files[1]):
    aux += (row_f1, row_f2)

print(f'printing f1\n{tup_files[0]}\n')
print(f'printing f2\n{tup_files[1]}\n')
print(f'printing aux\n{aux}')
```

#### Which Yields:

```
printing f1
(('843.19598', '2396.10278', '3579.13778', '4210.15674', '4209.37549'), 
 ('841.93976', '2397.21948', '3573.11963', '4205.89209', '4226.73926'),
 ('842.01642', '2397.72266', '3573.06494', '4202.88379', '4226.93799'),
 ('842.22083', '2397.47974', '3574.27515', '4204.19043', '4223.82088'),
 ('842.42065', '2397.20142', '3575.47437', '4205.52246', '4220.64795'))

printing f2
(('3586.02124', '2391.50342', '837.45227', '-837.29681', '-2385.97513'),
 ('3587.69238', '2387.48218', '836.60445', '-840.75067', '-2390.17529'), 
 ('3588.44531', '2387.44556', '836.00555', '-840.79022', '-2389.77612'), 
 ('3588.08203', '2388.25439', '836.26544', '-840.17017', '-2389.07544'), 
 ('3587.66553', '2389.05566', '836.53046', '-839.53912', '-2388.40405'))

printing aux
(('843.19598', '2396.10278', '3579.13778', '4210.15674', '4209.37549'), 
 ('3586.02124', '2391.50342', '837.45227', '-837.29681', '-2385.97513'), 
 ('841.93976', '2397.21948', '3573.11963', '4205.89209', '4226.73926'), 
 ('3587.69238', '2387.48218', '836.60445', '-840.75067', '-2390.17529'), 
 ('842.01642', '2397.72266', '3573.06494', '4202.88379', '4226.93799'), 
 ('3588.44531', '2387.44556', '836.00555', '-840.79022', '-2389.77612'), 
 ('842.22083', '2397.47974', '3574.27515', '4204.19043', '4223.82088'), 
 ('3588.08203', '2388.25439', '836.26544', '-840.17017', '-2389.07544'), 
 ('842.42065', '2397.20142', '3575.47437', '4205.52246', '4220.64795'), 
 ('3587.66553', '2389.05566', '836.53046', '-839.53912', '-2388.40405'))
```

Results using tuples as required.